# Why movie actors also called as artist ?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Definition of Artist: ***a person who creates paintings or drawings as a profession or hobby.***

Definition of Actor:  ***a person who acts in a play, film, broadcast, etc***

There is huge difference between Artist & Actor, then why both equal?

May be people mistake Leonardo da Vinci with Leonardo DiCaprio.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You seem to have focused on the first definition of artist, but forgotten about the second. Have a look at sense 1.1 in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/artist). By the way, you [**must** include where you got your quotes from](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: _Artist_ is one of many, many, many, English words which have more than one meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because acting is considered as an art. Many Indian colleges award bachelor's degree of arts with subject acting. As a result, actors are also called artists. For example,  see the following:

> [BACHELOR OF FINE ARTS - ACTING](http://theatre.msu.edu/index.php?cID=264)
>
> The Bachelor of Fine Arts degree in Theatre is designed for students wishing to prepare for a professional career in theatre. […] In addition to required theatre education courses, **students choose an area of concentration in either acting or design.** The concentration provides highly focused course work devoted to professional and practical skill development and production process and collaboration.
>
> <sub><sup>Michigan State University College of Arts and Letters</sup></sub>

Comment: You need to put spaces after every period in your post. Linking just a website is not encouraged in this community as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please include essential parts of the link in your post.

Comment: Looks far better than before. +1) Happy holiday!

Comment: Actually I did that in hurry because I was going to attend a meeting,by the way it's working day for me...

Answer (score 0):

The most correct answer to your question is that by no means is your supplied definition of the word artist even remotely accurate or generally accepted.

All painters are artists, but not all artists are painters.